# Sharing a variable within two activities?

Tags: java, android

I have created two activities in my android application.

The variable is declared in the activity 1. Now I want to use that variable, update it's values in activity 2 as well as activity 1 simultaneously. And the activities should use the latest values for that variable.

I guess we can do this using Intents, but I want to know any other simpler method.

Comment: use shared preferences

Comment: What is the variable?

Comment: Use shared preference as suggested or use static variable in a utility class in case its singleton instance. I usually keep following variables static: `DateFormatter`, reuseable Gson object, Custom loaded Fonts etc. Anything that won't cause memory leak and can be singleton.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharedPreferences

To retrieve data from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) 
{
  int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
  int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);     
}
```

To edit data from sharedpreference

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("text", mSaved.getText().toString());
 editor.putInt("selection-start", mSaved.getSelectionStart());
 editor.putInt("selection-end", mSaved.getSelectionEnd());
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

The android documentation is good place to start:

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

```
  Singleton class
```

> You can take advantage of the fact that your application components
>   run in the same process through the use of a singleton. This is a
>   class that is designed to have only one instance. It has a static
>   method with a name such as getInstance() that returns the instance;
>   the first time this method is called, it creates the global instance.
>   Because all callers get the same instance, they can use this as a
>   point of interaction. For example activity A may retrieve the instance
>   and call setValue(3); later activity B may retrieve the instance and
>   call getValue() to retrieve the last set value.

Comment: why voting down on my aswer while in the documentation they mentioned static as a way to go?

Comment: I did not down vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this variable on your custom `Application` class as you can get to the application from each activity by calling `getApplication()` method.

```
public class YourApplicationextends Application {

    public String yourVariable;

    // the rest of the code

}
```

You can declare your custom application class in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApplication"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you pass parameter between activities

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondClass.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("passThisParam", passThisParam);
                Log.d("log tag","param passed===>>>"+passThisParam);
                startActivity(i);
```

and to receive this parameter in next activity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
// Selected image id
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way (**not the correct way**) is to create a global variable accessible to both activities.

Example

Declare variable in one of the activities as public and static like this:

FirstActivity.java

```
public static String variable = "value";
```

In the other activity you can access and modify the variable like this:

SecondActivity.java

```
FirstActivity.variable = "newValue";
```

Now if you print the variable in any of those activities the value should be "newValue"

If you want to do this correctly you should consider a Singleton class, SharedPreferences or using Intents. It takes a little bit more of work, but in the end you have a more robust piece of code.